# doctrine2 odm for mongodb isn't saving the clone's nested objects

Tags: php, mongodb, doctrine-orm

so i have a school, each school has multiple bell schedules and each schedule has details:

```
school (document)
-- bell schedule (embedded document)
---- bell schedule details (embedded document)
```

when i clone the school object and print_r the school, it comes back with the proper objects in the clone.  however, when i try to persist the school, it doesn't save the details properly.  is there something that I need to do in order for this to work properly?  is there a flag I need to set or something?

what im trying to do is:

```
$school2 = clone $school1;
$dm->persist($school2);
$dm->flush();

---- classes ----

    /**
     * @MongoDB\Document(collection="schools")
     */
    class School
    {   
        /**
         * @MongoDB\EmbedMany
         */
        protected $bell_schedules = array();

        public function addBellSchedules(BellSchedule $bellSchedules)
        {
            $this->bell_schedules[] = $bellSchedules;
        }

        public function getBellSchedules()
        {
            return $this->bell_schedules;
        }

        public function setBellSchedules(\Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection $bell_schedules)
        {
            $this->bell_schedules = $bell_schedules;
            return $this;
        }
    }


    /**
     * @MongoDB\EmbeddedDocument
     */
    class BellSchedule
    {
        /**
         * @MongoDB\EmbedMany
         */
        private $bell_schedule_details

        public function getBellScheduleDetails()
        {
            return $this->bell_schedule_details;
        }

        public function setBellScheduleDetails(\Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection $bell_schedule_details)
        {
            $this->bell_schedule_details = $bell_schedule_details;
            return $this;
        }
    }

    /**
     * @MongoDB\EmbeddedDocument
     */
    class BellScheduleDetail
    {    
        private $period;
        private $label;
    }
```

Comment: Can you share your class mappings (e.g. annotations, XML, YML)? Also, if need to dump managed objects, you might find the `\Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump()` function useful, as it ignores references to internal Doctrine services that can easily clutter up normal `var_dump()` and `print_r()` output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `@EmbedMany` annotations are missing the `targetDocument` attribute, which should correspond to the class name of the embedded object(s). See the [annotation reference](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#embedmany) for more information. Also, you are missing field mappings for the BellScheduleDetail class. You may want to use [@String](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#string) for those fields.

Lastly, I would advise initializing your EmbedMany and ReferenceMany fields as ArrayCollection instances rather than empty arrays. That way you can always expect the property to be a Collection implementation (either ArrayCollection or PersistentCollection). It may not make much difference in your case (using the `[]` operator), but it can come in handy if you find yourself doing other array operations on the property.